# Geometry node curve splines interpolation

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to populate in-between splines positions by several (user defined number) of splines. How can I achieve this ?
In this example, my curve has 3 splines: I can deform splines along normal, and to their respective sides, I would like to fill with other splines between given extreme positions.

[image: Moving curves]

Edit : Solution:
We need to instanciate via mesh line and instance on point, then capture spline indices:

[image: Solution animated]

[image: node tree normal]

[image: node tree side]

The Blender file with solution :
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Mix Node is interesting to interpolate positions for one curve, but my main problem is : how to populate with several curves ? (ie : 6 in my example, but could be more)

Comment: [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260561/how-do-i-interpolate-two-b%c3%a9zier-curves-and-create-instances-in-between) is not similar and does not solve my problem