# Absolute shape key morph in Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am using blender 3.6. I am attempting to morph 3 curve shapes in a linear action within geometry nodes. Similar to using absolute shape keys. I plan to use a bone to drive the linear morphing action. Does anyone have any insight into producing such a node group.
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a *sample curve* node to get the shape from two of the curves to the last one.

- What you do is put a *set position* on either the last curve or first curve
- then you use two sample curves (you could technically use one. ask me if you really want to know) each sampling from one of the other curves (put the curves you are sampling from into the curve input of the *sample curve*)
- set the *sample curve* to factor (unless you want to use cyclic curves in which case ask me) and use the spline parameter as the factor.
- use two mix nodes (set to vector) to mix between the two output positions from the *sample curve*'s.
  This is set up with the fist position you want in the input `A` of the first mix, the second position in the `B` of the fist mix, the put the output of the fist mix into the `A` of the second mix, and the lest (3rd) position into the `B` of the second mix.
- this goes into the position of the set position.

---

I just remembered I saw some similar: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/260574/165102

Comment: I really appreciate your answers, but please make sure your wording is precise and correct if you don't want to use images, because right now it's hard to understand (in some places) what you're trying to say. Thank you!